# does solidity compiler convert to immutable implicitly?

Tags: solc, constructor, immutable

I was wondering if the solidity compiler automatically sets a state variable to immutable if it is never modified?

example

```
contract MyContract {
  uint256 myNumber;

  constructor(uint256 _myNumber){
    myNumber = _myNumber;
  }

  // nowhere else in the contract does myNumber gets modified only read
}
```

My question is will the solidity compiler convert that state variable to immutable without me explicitly declaring it immutable?